# Don't show notification to user again after closing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a notification bar on my site that I don't want to be shown to users again on subsequent visits after they close it the first time. The bar works as expected, but I can't seem to get the cookie to work to not display it again. I am using the jquery cookie plugin (I know this has been replaced, but I inherited the site).

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#notification-bar").length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#notification-bar").animate({ height: "100px" }, 500);
        }, 500);

        $("#notification-bar .close").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $notifBar = $("#notification-bar");
            $notifBar.css("display", "none");
            var cookieName = $notifBar.attr("data-cookie");

            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            try {
                document.cookie =
                    "closed_" + cookieName + "=1;expires=" + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
            } catch (ignore) { }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification-bar">
    <div class="container">
        This is the notification bar!
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the logic to check if the cookie is set before displaying the notification? Furthermore, have you verified the cookie is set? You ignore exceptions there so perhaps there's one which you don't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-cookie` attribute is missing (do you need this?), and you never actually check the cookie.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
// fake document.cookie for testing
var document = {cookie:""};
    if ($("#notification-bar").length > 0 && document.cookie.indexOf("closed_" + $("#notification-bar").attr("data-cookie")+"=1") < 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#notification-bar").animate({ height: "100px" }, 500);
        }, 500);

        $("#notification-bar .close").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $notifBar = $("#notification-bar");
            $notifBar.css("display", "none");
            var cookieName = $notifBar.attr("data-cookie");
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            try {
                document.cookie =
                    "closed_" + cookieName + "=1;expires=" + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
            } catch (ignore) { }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification-bar" data-cookie="notifbar">
    <div class="container">
        This is the notification bar!
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate your help- this works great.